# SELECT and UPDATE statements don't execute in JSP page within inline statements

Tags: mysql, jsp, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud SQL (mySQL) as my repository for a JSP page.  I have other pages that are working fine doing SELECT statements but when I use the same code to try and apply a multiple step operation the database does not update the record.  The code is

```
    Connection c = null;
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://database info here");
    ResultSet rsAddOrder = c.createStatement().executeQuery("INSERT INTO Orders (title) SELECT title FROM OrderHistory WHERE id = 1");
    ResultSet rsUpdateOrderBuyer = c.createStatement().executeQuery("UPDATE Orders SET Buyer = 'test4@mail.com', Purchase = '55' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I'm trying to grab a record from a table and then do an insert to copy the record into a new table.  The additional steps are to update the buyer email and add the purchase order number.  Is it failing because I'm doing multiple operations?

Comment: At this stage I can't change the code too much from the JSP and inline SQL statements in case people recommend another design approach.  Thanks

Comment: This could be related to what is mentioned in this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869422/using-google-cloud-sql-during-java-appengine-development-instead-of-local-mysql - Could you try with "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/" and let me know if it worked?. Also have a look at managing your connections at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/